# Who knows this convex polytope?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, polytopes

I hope this is not too trivial for this forum. I was wondering if someone has come across this polytope.

You start with the [rhombic dodecahedron](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RhombicDodecahedron.html), subdivide it into four parallellepipeds, [image]

and then fill the space between the four parallellepipeds with a tetrahedron, six parallellepipeds and four prisms (hopefully I counted correctly), so as to obtain a convex polytope.

Does this have a name? could someone provide a link to a picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this it?

          
[image: Rhombic Dodecahedron + Tetrahedron]

Comment: wow thanks. i think so, although it would help a lot if it could be seen from other perspectives, or even exploded according to the above subdivision.

Comment: This doesn't look right to me. I would expect faces that are adjacent to equilateral triangles to all be rectangles. In your left picture, they look more like rhombi...

Comment: @André: I don't doubt you.  I formed this as the Minkowski sum of a rhombic dodecahedron and a regular tetrahedron, but perhaps I did not scale one with respect to the other appropriately.  Cannot check now...

Answer (score 7):

It's the [Minkowski sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of the rhombic dodecahedron with a regular tetrahedron.
(The rhombic dodecahedron is it self the Minkowski sum of four segments).

Comment: indeed. have you casually seen a picture of it with the decomposition written in the question?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to ressemble the "Self-Dual Icosioctahedron #4" :

http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/SelfDualIcosioctahedron4.html

Some code:

```
sage: P = polytopes.rhombic_dodecahedron()
sage: Q = polytopes.tetrahedron()
sage: R = P.minkowski_sum(Q)
sage: R.f_vector()
(1, 28, 54, 28, 1)
sage: R.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned **Minkowski sum** is just an example of **Alicia Boole Stott's expansion** operation(s), cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_(geometry)

--- rk